# how to figure out your p12 password made in openssl when publishing for iOS in flash CS5.5?

Tags: ios, flash, openssl, certificate, pkcs#12

I've finished up development in flash for my iphone app, payed for the dev license, and used this [tutorial](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f-19aa73f128cc9f05e8-8000.html#WSfffb011ac560372f46768d8712cd1d13954-7ffd) to use openSSL to make my p12 file.  I have the provisioning profile downloaded from apple and the p12 done, but I have no clue how to figure out the password of the p12.  When I publish flash tells me "could not load keystore files (password may be incorrect).  So basically I need to know how to figure out the password.  I'm completely new to openssl so I'm not sure if there's something I need to add in the code or what?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is just to export your certificate from your "Keychain Access" application. When you export it (in .p12 format) you have to add a password which you will use in flash. This option is available only if you are using MAC OS.